# Comma required or not

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence

I was writing the following sentence and I'm puzzled which one would be the correct sentence. In my humble opinion, the second sentence looks wrong as a comma is not required. The second part of the sentence "I received..," is an independent sentence, and it is better to use a conjunction like *which*, or *that*, or maybe a comma is not required at all.

> 1. I am writing this letter to express my dissatisfaction on the laptop repair service I received from you service center.
> 2. I am writing this letter to express my dissatisfaction on the laptop repair service, I received from you service center.
> 3. I am writing this letter to express my dissatisfaction on the laptop repair service that I received from you service center.

Comment: 2nd version is correct apart from replacing "on" with "with".  "_ ... my dissatisfaction **with** the laptop repair service that I received from ..._". You don't really need the "that" either. "_I am writing this letter to express my dissatisfaction with the laptop repair service I received from you service center._"

Comment: also *you**r** service center*

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a comma in this sentence.  However, the section from *'I received..."* onward is not an independent sentence; in fact, *"the laptop repair service I received from your service center"* is a noun phrase, so there is no benefit to putting a comma in to break it up.  You could say '**that** I received', or (better in my opinion) '**which** I received...', but sentence 1 as it stands (with the addition of the final **r** on '**your**') is perfectly intelligible.

And I'd definitely say 'dissatisfaction **with**...'

With my editor's hat on, I might suggest recasting the sentence to make it pithier:

*"I am writing this letter to express my dissatisfaction.
Recently, I took my laptop in to your service centre..."*

But that's style, not grammar.